# 7 years later: same issue - same incomplete error message Fails on 'file not found' but doesn't specify target

Tags: locale

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

This started happening after a dist-upgrade from Debian Jessie to Stretch (on the way to Buster).

Query it here and the same problem has been happening for years.

The error message doesn't specify what file it not found.

What amazes me more (after reading multiple threads) is nobody picks up on this. It's like it's OK to put out incomplete error messages.

Linux has reached a level of complexity that finding out who owns this code and asking for changes is somewhere between a part-time job and a Quixotic quest

We can't help you if you won't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: What's the default locale on your system?

Comment: I downvoted you because of the unnecessary rant

Comment: It SHOULD be unnecessary.

Comment: The default locale: en-ca:UTF8

Comment: That locale name looks totally bogus. I have no idea if older system accepted `en-ca:UTF8` instead of `en_CA.UTF-8`, but my Debian Buster certainly does not. Where was it set? Does `grep en-ca /etc/locale.gen` give anything? If yes, uncomment the line and run `locale-gen` (as already mentioned `dpkg-reconfigure` should do that automatically).

Comment: +1 for the glorious rant.  You don't mention *when* you see this error. Apologies if it's obvious to others.  Is this an error in your logs, or when you login at the terminal, or when you explicitly set your locale?

Answer (score 2):

`No such file or directory` is the error message associated with the `ENOENT` error code.

That's short for *Error NO ENTry*, so typically associated with the fact that a directory didn't have an entry by the given name, but it also often used to say *doesn't exist*, even if that's not specifically about a given file.

Alternatively, sometime `ESRCH` is used. That's *Error SeaRCH*, but the corresponding error message in English is generally `No such process` which in the end is more confusing if the error is not specifically about processes.

Anyway, in your case, the error tells you either the locale could not be found. It may or may not be refering to an actual file, but that's hardly relevant.

Here, if I do:

```
$ LC_ALL=foo locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
$ LC_ALL=foo strace locale 2>&1 | grep ENOENT
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/foo/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/foo/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/foo/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I do see some system calls failing with the `ENOENT` error, but the paths are not necessarily relevant to the error.

For a locale that does exist, I see:

```
$ strace locale 2>&1 | grep /usr/lib/locale
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

It doesn't need to look for extra files, as all the information is in that `locale-archive`.

`locale -a` will tell you the list of available locales on your system. If any of the `LC_*` or `LANG` environment variables contain something not in that list, that's where you'll see this kind of errors.

How to make more locales available is system dependant.

On Debian, that's generally with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. Generally, eventually, locales end up being compiled from sources using the `localedef` standard command.

Comment: I did all that. Checked the locales etc. Also Debian advises against setting LC_ALL to anything

Comment: > Warning! Using LC_ALL is strongly discouraged as it overrides everything. Please use it only when testing and never set it in a startup file. https://wiki.debian.org/Locale

Comment: And I'm really looking for the definitive interpretation of the error message.

Comment: @NetScribe set your locale to a proper value (i.e. `en_CA.UTF-8`) and start from there